# Directory not found when using ng --open serve

Tags: angular

[image]I am trying to open my angular project using `ng --open serve`, but its showing error no such file or directory is found but am in the same angular-project. It was working before.

> D:\Programming\HTML\Angular_Tutorial\first-app>ng --open serve
> ⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\Programming\HTML\Angular_Tutorial\first-app\first-app'
> See "C:\Users\MagNusS\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-p31yQF\angular-errors.log" for further details.

package.json:

{
"name": "first-app",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
"bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.2.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
"karma": "~6.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"typescript": "~4.3.2"
}
}

Comment: Can you show the file explorer contents of `D:\Programming\HTML\Angular_Tutorial\first-app`

Comment: If it was working before, what did you change?

Comment: I didn't changed any crucial elements.

Comment: Can you please provide the contents of your package.json file?